# How to resolve object is not assignable to type any[] error?

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Ionic/Angular project how would I resolve the error that says

> 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

my code so far:

```
    export class HomePage {

  todayEvents: [];

  constructor( public dataService: DataServiceProvider) {
     this.getTodayEvents();     
  }

    getTodayEvents() {
    this.dataService.getTodayEvents().subscribe(events => {
      this.todayEvents = events;     
      console.log(events);
    });

  }


}
```

And this is what is logged to console on my api call: It seems like an array but I'm missing something because typescript doesnt like it...

```
{data: Array(2)}
data
:
Array(2)
0
:
{id: 1, client_id: 1, starts_at: "2017-11-18 12:30:00", ends_at: "2017-11-18 14:30:00", completed: "3", …}
1
:
{id: 1, client_id: 1, starts_at: "2017-11-19 12:30:00", ends_at: "2017-06-27 14:30:00", completed: "3", …}
```

DataService
//I remove .map because in the new common/Http is no longer required.

```
getTodayAppointments() {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl);
    // No longer necessary in http/common ....map((res: Response) => res.json());  
}
```

Comment: `events` is an object (hence the error) with a `data` property which contains an array of events.

Comment: You can try: `this.todayEvents = events.data`.

Comment: this.todayEvents = events.data works when the app runs. However VS code highlights .data with error Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'? Do I just have to put up with this or there is a way of fixing it? @ConnorsFan

Comment: Maybe declaring `.subscribe(events: any =>` would remove the VS Code error message.

Comment: did you share service method code ?

Comment: Did you try declaring `events: any` as suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes. It had no effect on the highlighting

Comment: Another suggestion: `subscribe(events: { data: Array<any> } => `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :

```
export class HomePage {

    todayEvents: Array<any> = [];

    constructor(public dataService: DataServiceProvider) {
        this.getTodayEvents();
    }

    getTodayEvents() {
        this.dataService.getTodayEvents().subscribe(events => {
            this.todayEvents = events.data;
            console.log(events);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: try to declare todatEvents variable like todayEvents: Array<any> = []; ?

Comment: It works. but event.data is where my issue is. It is highlighted as an error even though it works.