# angular - Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to get data from a Django backend via a REST framework. I am using Angular 2 and the HttpClient & HttpClientModule modules, and basing my code off of a previous (working) project that used the Http module. When I run my code, I get an error stating that "Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?". I am super new to Angular (this is only the second service I've ever written, and the first with HttpClient) and I am not sure how to correct this. I've looked at several similar questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513945/type-object-is-not-assignable-to-type-any) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368505/how-to-resolve-object-is-not-assignable-to-type-any-error) but I'm not sure how to generalize the answers back to a service instead of a component.

My code is here:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class FacultyService {
  private apiURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/faculty';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFaculty() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL)
      .toPromise()
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error('An error occured', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }      

}
```

Comment: The error say you that you received a Object and want to save in an array.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response